# "ActivityName.this" How to convert C#?

Tags: android, xamarin

i like use a ActivityName.this (Java Code)

How to convert to C#(Xamarin)?

"this" is not a member of ActivityName

thanks.

```
public static class a{
public staric void DoWork(Context context){}
}

class b{
a.DoWork((Context)ActivityName)<- error is type but is used like a variable
a.DoWork(ActivityName) <- error is type but is used like a variable
a.DoWork(ActivityName.Context) <-no member Conttext
a.DoWork(ActivityName.this)<-no member this
}
```

class b is not Activity so this Just not available

Comment: `ActivityName.Context` ?

Comment: @Blackbelt "Context" is not member for ActivityName

Comment: why don't you use just `this` ?

Comment: add code, you can see class b ,  class b is not Activity

Comment: It did so reluctantly
1. make context of activities
2. Transmit to the class

Comment: if your class is not subclass of activity, you don't have any other means to retrieve the Context, than providing it as parameter

Comment: @Blackbelt Okay.thanks. ..and... Java also is same?

Comment: I would like to know how to the sub-class approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `this` word for Activity.
If you write your app in Xamarin you should use just `this` keyword.
Please see this, I am creating new CustomProgressDialog object:

```
CustomProgressDialog _customProgressDialog = new CustomProgressDialog(this);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Calls from normal class(not activity) , so i can't just use this

Comment: @Andromer then you would probably have to pass it from the activity to the class you need it in.

Comment: @danny  also like JAVA?

Comment: @Andromer What do you mean like Java?:)

Comment: @danny In Java, (not C #)  Do you can skip "pass it from the activity" ? use the ActivityNama.this

Comment: @Andromer I am not sure if I understand.
In Java notification is: ActivityName.this,
In C# you use: this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be helpful for you -> For example if you have this code in Java

```
orientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this) {
    @Override
    public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
        MainActivity.this.onOrientationChanged(orientation);
    }
};
```

You could transfer it to this one in C# (Xamarin)

```
var myOrientationListener = new MyListener();
myOrientationListener.OrientationChanged += (s, e) => {
     MyActivity.onOrientationChanged(e);
};
```

For a whole example, take a look at this forum post http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32576/need-help-porting-java-to-c-how-to-handle-anonymous-inner-class

Comment: Unfortunately, the constructor does not apply only Myactivity